# How can I transfer TextView to ListView

Tags: android

I have two activities. The first activity has one `TextView`, and the second activity has one `ListView`. I couldn't transfer between the two via an intent. I must transfer data momentarily. Because I have a timer in the first activity, when the timer goes to `0`, then the second activity will start. I must show results in second activity `ListView`.

Comment: can you post code that you have done?

Comment: I dont get it, you dont want to transfer the textviews content to the 2nd activity **OR** you want it but didnt work??

Comment: I want to transfer textview content to the 2nd activity. But I can't do it.. And I have no idea how can I do it so there is no code Mahesh Giri

Comment: When I click button first activitys textview change. When it change I want to transfer this info to 2nd activity listview..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an arraylist for this. First declare an arraylist in your first activity.

```
ArrayList<String> clickeddata=new ArrayList<String>();
```

On button click add the text from textview to arraylist.

```
clickeddata.add(your_textview.getText().toString());
```

And when counter is 0 send the arraylist to the second activity.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Your_First_Activity.this, Your_second_Activity.class);
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("sentdata", clickeddata);
    startActivity(intent);
```

On second Activity receive it by following code

```
    Intent i = getIntent(); 
    ArrayList<String> mylist=new ArrayList<String>(); 
    mylist = i.getStringArrayListExtra("sentdata");
```

Now you can create listview by simple adapter like.

```
   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mylist);
   your_list_view.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: The method getdata() is undefined for the type TextView

Comment: I have one more error. " Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<String> to String[] " my string module is like; String[] veriler = new String[] {"USA", "UK"};

Comment: i think the anser given already is an anwser to your question. in your question there is no mention of any string[] and i dnt know where your string[] is how it is.. so cant solve this problem. Do as i have done and the problem will be solved

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by Intent

```
Intent intent=new Intent(Context,SecondActivity);
 intent.putExtra("key",textView.getText().toString());
 startActivity(intent);
```

In Second Activity

```
String data=getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
```

and use it.

Comment: Man I know this code. But I can't use it. I want to do it momentarily.

Comment: How can I connect it to list?
        bossonuc = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.bossonuc);
        bossonuc.setText("boş sayınız: " + getIntent().getExtras().getString("bosveri"));

I can do it text but I can't do with list..

Comment: i don't get it.can you explain in more detail.